# Corona : ScoreText writing new score over the old one

Tags: lua, coronasdk, scoring

My code writes the score ( final score) over the old one ( without deleting it) So when it's counting again we can actually see the old score ( the last one that the player had) written on the back of the counter. ( and when it shows the new highscore, we can also see the old one on the back )

```
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

--physics.setContinuous( false ) 

local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

display.setDefault( "anchorX", 0 )
display.setDefault( "anchorY", 0 )


--local mydata = require( "mydata" )
--mydata.score = 0
    score = 0

function scene:createScene(event)

local screenGroup = self.view

sky = display.newImage("bg.jpg")
sky.x = 820; sky.y = 0. sky.rotation = 90 
screenGroup:insert(sky)

mountain1 = display.newImage("montagne2.png")
mountain1.x = -200; mountain1.y = 600
mountain1.speed = 0.5
screenGroup:insert(mountain1)
end

local scoreNumber = display.newText(score, 400, 0, nil, 50)
    scoreNumber.xScale = 1.2
    scoreNumber.yScale = 1.2

    if scoreNumber then 
    scoreNumber:removeSelf()
    end

local function updateScore()
    score = score + 1
    scoreNumber.text = score
    --mydata.score = mydata.score + 1

end

    scoreTimer = timer.performWithDelay(100, updateScore, -1)



local scoreText = display.newText("score:", 0, 0, nil, 50)
    scoreText.xScale = 1.2
    scoreText.yScale = 1.2
    screenGroup:insert( scoreNumber)




end

function scene:exitScene(event)


    Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", touchScreen)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mountain1)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mountain2)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mountain3)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mountain4)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", missile1)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", obst1)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", obst2)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", obst3)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", obst4)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", obst5)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", obst6)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("collision", onCollision)
    timer.cancel(scoreTimer)
     timer.cancel(memTimer)

end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

Comment: your code not clear.

Comment: Is there a question too?

Comment: @RobMiracle  (I had some connection issues) , yes the question here is that : How can I prevent the code from writing the new score over the older one ? after a game over, even my score counter starts over the last one. It seems to me that after a game over, the score text saved is kept somehow under the new one.

Comment: Are you using a scene manager like Composer or Storyboard?  Can you update your post with more code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure we are seeing enough code or more importantly the right code, but there are a couple of things going on.

```
local scoreNumber = display.newText(score, 400, 0, nil, 50)
scoreNumber.xScale = 1.2
scoreNumber.yScale = 1.2

if scoreNumber then 
     scoreNumber:removeSelf()
end
```

In this block of code, you create scoreNumber and immediately remove it. You also never add it to the scene's view group: screenGroup:insert( scoreNumber)

```
local function updateScore()
    score = score + 1
    scoreNumber.text = score
    --mydata.score = mydata.score + 1
 end
 scoreTimer = timer.performWithDelay(100, updateScore, -1)
```

This will likely crash your app since every 100 milliseconds (1/10th of a second) you call updateScore, which tries to reference scoreNumber which you removed right above it.

```
local scoreText = display.newText("score:", 0, 0, nil, 50)
scoreText.xScale = 1.2
scoreText.yScale = 1.2
```

Now you've created scoreText, but I never see you insert it into the screenGroup, nor do I see you ever update it's value.

You have a lot of other things going on. I don't see where you're setting the default anchor points (if you even are) and if you're not, display objects are centered on their X and Y values. So scoreNumber, for the brief time it draws will be centered 400px from the left and 0px from the top. This puts at least the top half of the text off screen. Then you scale it up for some reason. Why not just use a larger font? 50 * 1.2 = 60.  Then scoreText is drawn at 0, 0 which not only puts the top half off screen, it puts the left half off screen.

Remember if you want Storyboard to manage your display objects, they must be inserted in to the screenGroup for you and you should not have to remove them yourself.

Comment: hi there, I just got back my hard drive it was stollen . Now I'm starting back my  project sorry for delay.

Comment: I've added the score to my screen group, now the problem is that the score goes of after the gamer loses, instead of just freezing so that the player can see his final score ( I've updated my code above )